# Allocate string (char*) in another function

Tags: c, malloc

How do I (m)allocate string in another function? I've tried to do it by 2 ways (down in code JUST EXAMPLE - I wouldn't do it with argv).

```
void someFunction(char* string, char** argv) {
    string = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
    strcpy(string,argv[2]);
    // string[strlen(argv[2]) + 1] = '\0' //should I do this now?
    printf("%s",string); //outputs string (works fine)
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *string; 
    char *string2;

    someFunction(string,argv);
    printf("%s",string); //outputs (null)
    free(string);

    someFunction(&*string2,argv);
    printf("%s",string2); //outputs (null)
    free(string2);
}
```

I want to use "string" in main, but mallocate it in different function.

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what is your question, and/or what is the problem?

Comment: @TonyB I want to use "string" in main, but mallocate it in different function. Is it possible? And how to send mallocated string as pointer? If I will use someFunction(string,argv), I won't be able to free that memory.

Comment: Without running it, what do you think `void f(int i) {i = 7;} int main(void) {int x = 5; f(x); printf("%i\n", x); return 0;}` prints?

Comment: @immibis It prints 5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
void someFunction(char** string, char** argv) {
    *string = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
    strcpy(*string, argv[2]);
    // string[strlen(argv[2]) + 1] = '\0' //should I do this now?
    printf("%s",*string); //outputs string (works fine)
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *string; 
    char *string2;

    someFunction(&string,argv);
    printf("%s",string);
    free(string);
}
```

Comment: Well, it fails to free the string for me when I use `strcpy(*string,'txt')` but that's not a part of my question.

Comment: @Lucfia What makes you think that `free` fails here?

Comment: sorry, I mean  `strcat(*string,'txt')`

Comment: I believe it's more natural if you return the allocated string from that function.

Comment: I don't see any `strcat` in your question. And it's `strcat(*string,"txt")` and not `strcat(*string,'txt')`. Maybe you should ask another question.

Comment: `strcat` may cause problems if the buffer is not long enough. E.g. you allocate 6 bytes for the string "Hello". And then you do `strcat`on that buffer, which will write beyond the end of the buffer causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelWalz THANK YOU! Atleast you solved my st**id mistake in all of my programs :)).

Answer (score 4):

Here are two examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void alloc1 (char **new_string, char *text) {
  *new_string = malloc(strlen(text)+1);
  strcpy (*new_string, text);
}

char * alloc2(char *text) {

  char *new_string = malloc(strlen(text)+1);
  strcpy (new_string, text);
  return new_string;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *s;

  /* Make sure we entered a command line argument */
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf ("USAGE: myprog SOMETHING\n");
    return 1;
  }

  alloc1(&s, argv[1]);
  printf ("alloc1: s=%s\n", s);
  free (s);

  s = alloc2 (argv[1]);
  printf ("alloc2: s=%s\n", s);
  free (s);

  return 0;
}
```

The first example passes a pointer to a pointer: your main allocates the pointer; the function allocates the space to the pointer; the pointer itself is [passed by reference](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/references.html).

The second example is similar, except the pointer is returned by the function instead of altering the reference.

The first is "cleaner" if you're only initializing one pointer; the second is useful if you want to return *multiple* different values in the same function.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!)