# Free allocated string after strcat

Tags: c, malloc, strcat

According to the [Allocate string (char*) in another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437864/allocate-string-char-in-another-function) I have now code like this:

```
 void someFunction(char** string, char** argv) {
    *string = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
    strcpy(*string, argv[2]);
    strcat(*string, ".txt"); //works fine without this
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *string; 
    char *string2;

    someFunction(&string,argv);
    printf("%s",string);
    free(string); // freezes here due the strcat
}
```

After adding strcat to the code from the linked question, it freezes when I try to free my string.

Comment: That's probably because you allocated N+1 bytes and then stored N+5 bytes in it (where N is the length of the argument)

Comment: before writing lines like `strcat(*string, ".txt");`, think about where in memory you are writing to, and whether you are guaranteed there is enough space allocated to write in.

Comment: @immibis You're right! What a silly question.

Comment: Side-note: since this is C, you should not cast the return value from `malloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't allocate enough space for the resulting concatenated string; when you write past the end you invoke undefined behavior (in this case, likely heap corruption). Change the `malloc` to allocate `strlen(argv[2]) + strlen(".txt") + 1` so you have a large enough buffer to hold the whole string.

Comment: Note: `strlen(argv[2]) + sizeof(".txt")` also works, and would be faster, but it's a little more obscure, and people often make mistakes with `sizeof`, so I left the mention of it for a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Function `someFunction` has a bug. It does not allocate enough memory to append 
`".txt"`.

It could look the following way

```
 void someFunction(char** string, char** argv) {
    *string = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1 + 4 );
    strcpy(*string, argv[2]);
    strcat(*string, ".txt"); //works fine without this
}
```

However in any case the design of the function is bad. It uses magic number 2 in the expression `argv[2]` . If the function deals with `argv[2]` then there is no sense to pass as an argument the whole array pf pointers `argv`. You should just pass `argv[2]`. Moreover it uses parameter `string` by reference but does not free the memory that the parameter can point to. So its interface is confusing.

You can use the function shown in my answer to the question
[Safe way to concat two strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437461/safe-way-to-concat-two-strings-in-c/36437698#36437698)

The function could be called like

```
char *string = getConcatString( argv[2], ".txt" );

if ( string ) puts( string );

free( string );
```